# PHP Rest Web Service Response

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest

I am new to writing web services and I cannot seem to figure this out! I have a simple php restful service that returns a json response, but I don't have any keys in the response (I don't know if that's the right term) What I get is something like this.

```
(
    (
    "name",
    qty,
    "image",
    "price",
    "date"
)
```

I am positive I am doing something wrong here.

Here is my service:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    class InventoryAPI {
    private $db;

    function __construct() {

    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');
    $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);

    }

    function __destruct() {
    $this->db->close();
    }

    function checkInv() {

    $query = "SELECT model, sku, quantity, stock_status_id, image, price, date_available FROM table_name";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $rows = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_row())
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    $result->close();
    $this->db->close();

    echo json_encode($rows);
    }

}

$api = new InventoryAPI;
$api->checkInv();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you will want to use fetch_assoc() instead of fetch_row().  fetch_assoc() will return an array with keys the same name as the columns.  fetch_row() will return an enumerated array based on the column position.  For example: model is 0, sku is 1.

You can always test this out by printing out the array.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row())
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
```